# How to set data in spinner from web service in android?

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner which have data from local side, every time this activity launch a call to web service has been done, from web service i and getting a spinner id, so my question is how to set spinner value according to sector id come from web service. Please see below code when i am making spinner :

```
            private Spinner sp_sector;
            Collections.sort(sectors_list);
            ArrayAdapter<String> sector_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    R.layout.spinner_item, sectors_list);
            sector_adapter
                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            sp_sector.setAdapter(sector_adapter);
```

Comment: What is the exact issue?

Comment: actually i am getting an id for spinner from web service, now i want to set value in spinner acording to got id from web service

Comment: i have already data in spinner from adapter which is made by local storage file....

Comment: now from web service id i want to check from existing adapter that which value is from the key = id from web service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this way..
Add the web service values to the 'String[] items' array

```
String[] items = new String[] {"Select One", "Two", "Three"};
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mySpinner);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
    items[0] = "One";
    selectedItem = items[position];
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
}
});
```

cheerz

Comment: can i set any text directly to spinner as default value ? like spiner.setDefaultValue("Something"); ????

Comment: above answer is perfectly working for me.. I couldn't find that way of add values to spinner like "spiner.setDefaultValue("Something");"

Answer (score 0):

Create a new Adapter and assign it to the Spinner.